# How to access the Request object outside an action in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to get access to data stored in the request object, however I am outside of an action.

Is there a way to get that data?

Answer (score 4):

It completely depends on what layer you are in.

If you are in the view (template, partial) there is a variable automatically populated called `$sf_request`.

If you are elsewhere you can get a hold of it with the context singleton by: `sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()`. The problem with this is that if for some reason the context hasnt been created then its going to be an issue. You can check this with `sfContext::hasInstance()` but if there is no context then you cant get at the request this way obviously.

You could also inject the request instance into whatever layer/object you need it with a listener on `context.load_factories`. Again though, this requires that the layer in which you use it is doing so after that event has been triggered (eg. a context has been initialized).

Basically what im getting at here is that there shouldnt really be a reason to access the request outside of a controller :-)

Comment: Where would you need to result to using "sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()" ?

Comment: I wouldnt reccomend doing it anywhere. You shouldnt really need to. Its already made available in the view in the view and pretty much anywhere else i can think of you could inject it either from setup logic in a controller, or via a listener on `context.load_factories`. But i cant think of anything that would need to use it beyond the controller layer.

Comment: `sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()` worked for me